# Как выполнить скрипты Google App Script параллельно?

Tags: многопоточность, google-apps-script, promise

Есть задача - выполнить запрос к Гугл таблицам и вернуть выбранные строки, в таблице 100000 (или 1000000) строк, есть ли возможность выполнить функцию поиска в гугл скрипте параллельно, и вернуть результат в вызывающий скрипт? Гугл предлагает использовать сервис `HtmlService`, в котором вызывать функции `google.script.run`. Но при таком подходе функции выполняются на клиенте, и не работают с сервисом `UrlFetchApp` (возвращается код IFrame, но не результат выполнения функций). В общем есть такой код `код.gs` (в данном примере функция `testGet()` имитирует реальную функцию):

```
function doGet(e){return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index')}
function testGet(){
  var time=Math.floor(Math.random()*10000)
  Utilities.sleep(time)
  return time
}
```

и такой код `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es6-promise/3.2.1/es6-promise.min.js">
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id='res'></div>
  <script>
   async function request(){
     return await Promise.all ( [
        new Promise(function ( resolve , reject ){
        google.script.run
        .withSuccessHandler (function (result) {
          console.log(result);
          resolve (result);
        })
        .withFailureHandler (function (error) {
          reject (error);
        })
        .testGet() ;}).then(function(res){return res}),
        new Promise(function ( resolve , reject ){
        google.script.run
        .withSuccessHandler (function (result) {
          console.log(result);
          resolve (result);
        })
        .withFailureHandler (function (error) {
          reject (error);
        })
        .testGet() ;}).then(function(res){return res})]
      )
      .then (function(results) {
        return results
      })};
      var responce=request()
      document.getElementById("res").innerHTML=responce 
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Этот код работает... в браузере, а когда вызываю его функцией:

```
function myFunction() {
 var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://script.google.com/macros/s/my_ID_sript/exec",{
 "muteHttpExceptions":true,
 "followRedirects":true
 })
 var s = response.getContentText()
 Logger.log(s)
}
```

В ответ приходит HTML страница с этими функциями обернутыми в iframe.

Есть ли решение данной задачи?

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению, невозможно как-то изменить вопрос, чтобы дать однозначный ответ. В общем случае рассмтривают два варианта параллельного исполнения, плюс пакетное исполнение на стороне API. Прежде чем окунуться в эти дебри, стоит отметить, что скрипты исполняются **строго последовательно**.

### Оркестровка на стороне клиента

В отличие от сервера, на стороне браузера, Google Apps Script, точнее его Client-Side API ничто не останавливает от параллельных вызовов. Пример `Promise` в вопросе ярко это показывает. Исчерпывающей информацией по этому поводу будет статья [Orchestration of Apps Scripts - parallel threads and defeating quotas](http://ramblings.mcpher.com/Home/excelquirks/gasthreader)

Важно понимать, что для реализации этого процесса потребуется *клиентская часть*.

### Пакетная обработка

Суть обработки заключается в одновременном вызове нескольких запросов `UrlFetchApp.fetchAll()`. И да, как ни парадоксально, скрипт, опубликованный как веб-приложение, может вполне сносно вызывать сам себя. Есть доказательство асинхронности этого процесса https://gist.github.com/brainysmurf/a5fec05743cc3fc85f7870d0c8a14b1e, но поиски на GitHub компонентов Адама - это еще то занятие.

В любом случае, этот процесс возможен. Для реализации потребуется публикация *web app*.

### Batching Requests

Как решение проблем с Google API, можно использовать пакетные вызовы (batching requests). В посте https://developers.googleblog.com/2018/03/discontinuing-support-for-json-rpc-and.html описывается, что было, и что стало, и как этим пользоваться.

Как вариант, я бы предложил решать задачу именно третьим вариантом с использованием  гомогенных пакетных запросов к соответствующим точкам Sheets API. Если коротко: "взял, набрал запросов, выполнил, получил результат, профит", при этом ваша точка выполнит только один запрос, т.е. никакой параллельности/асинхронности не потребуется. Пример, только с Календарем https://github.com/oshliaer/google-apps-script-snippets/blob/master/snippets/standalone_batch-create-calendar-events/batch.js

Comment: спасибо, 1й вариант однозначно не подходит, т.к. клиента нет, все скрипты выполняются из скрипта, 3й пока не очень понятен, остановлюсь на 2м, по моему у Адама есть интересные подходы.

Comment: Нет под рукой простого примера батча, но это реально то, что вам нужно. Вы получаете размер Таблицы и делаете несколько запросов к разным частям Таблицы по заданным диапазонам. Всего два физических запроса.

Comment: Добавил пример, правда, с Календарем.

Comment: Я вас понял, вы предлагаете отправлять пакеты с запросами к `doGet `функции, через конечную точку https://www.googleapis.com/batch, где они будут выполнены параллельно. Во второй вашей ссылке, нашел готовые решения этого подхода - https://github.com/classroomtechtools/modularLibraries.gs, там есть библиотека Requests.gs, которая делает тоже самое через `UrlFetchApp.fetchAll()`, а также там есть решения по работе с таблицей, где в частности батчится запись и удаление данных в таблице. Буду пробовать, решение закомментирую здесь. Спасибо.